# Where should I keep logging.log file if I develop spring mvc app on windows and deploy on Linux instance

Tags: linux, spring-mvc, logging

I have developed a spring web mvc application using log4j for logging on windows machine

My **log4j.properties** file has:-

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
**log4j.appender.file.File=C\:\Logs\loging.log**

My loging.log file is on path:- **C\:\Logs\loging.log**

But I have deployed war on Linux so how do I write a log file on common location ,so I can refer it from windows and Linux machine as well?